# UIWebView overlapping

Tags: iphone

hai good afternoon to everyone, I am developing an iPhone web application. In my application I have loaded two web pages in a single UIWebView. After this process has completed, one web page should hide or overlap others whenever they get the user-interaction. However, I don't need this yet. User-interaction also should remain so-far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two different webpages in one UIWebView. Instead, you should try to create two UIWebView objects and add them as a subview in a container view.

You can set these UIWebView objects' `frame`, `userInteractionEnabled`, `hidden` properties according to your needs.

Also, you should look at delegate methods of UIWebView. Those delegate methods are called when a page is finished loading or when there is an error exc.
You can read the documentation to learn more about delegate methods:
[UIWebViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)